# Swift: Remove Last Character from a String If It's a Forward Slash

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am using this code to check if the last char on a string is slash and remove it

```
if urlString.last == "/" {
    urlString = urlString.substring(to: urlString.index(before: urlString.endIndex))
}
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this in swift 3?

Comment: `dropLast()`? But I don't remember if it's Swift 3.

Comment: Actually a backslash is `"\"` 

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of removing the "/"?
If you try to create a url from multiple strings you can just create a `URL(string: "local.address.com")!` and use `url.appendingPathComponent("myString")`
This way appendingPathComponent will add the required "/" and you can work in your strings without them.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
var str = "Hello, World/"
    if str.last == "/" {
        str = String(str.dropLast())
    }
```

That function only removes one of them.

If you want to remove backslash, you need to use "\" instead of "/".

Comment: @HussainChhatriwala That's not a reason for a downvote though... it was _commented_ above... not answered

Answer (score 0):

using `url.standardizedFileURL` will remove the last backslash "/"

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/2293229-standardizedfileurl

Comment: No it won't. I just tested it with iOS 16, folder path ending in `/`